# Using fgets to store a double into a struct

Tags: c, struct, fgets

I'm a bit new to C programming and I keep running into this error. Previously I was using fscanf with %lf because age was a double but since I switched to fgets, I do not know how to get it to accept a double. I am attempting to read into a struct. Here's my relevant code:

> ```
> double age;
> ...
> while(fgets(Employees[i].age, 10, input) != 0)
> ```

gives me this error:

error: incompatible type for argument 1 of fgets
expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'double'

Comment: `fgets()` reads a character string (`char *`) not a double. You either want `fscanf()` or something like `strtod()` to post-process the read string into a `double`.

Answer (score 1):

`fgets` tries reads in a line of text, which isn't ideal for your situation, as you're only interested in the `double` values.

So instead of using `fgets`, you'll want to use `fscanf` with a `double` format string:

```
while(fscanf(input, "%lf", &Employees[i].age) == 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to read an entire line of text using `fgets()` and then try to parse it into values using `sscanf()`.

`sscanf()` works just like `fscanf()` and `scanf()` except that its first parameter is a character string pointer.

Reading an entire line at a time may make it easier to do certain things, such as reporting errors by line number or if a `sscanf()` fails, trying to convert the line using different format strings.

An example for fun:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char buffer[1024];
    const size_t buffer_size = sizeof(buffer);
    int line_number = 0;

    while( fgets(buffer, buffer_size, stdin) ) {
        size_t len = strlen(buffer);
        double value;

        line_number++;

        if( buffer[len-1] == '\n' ) {
            buffer[len-1] = '\0';
            len--;
        }

        if( sscanf(buffer, " %lf", &value) != 1 ) {
            fprintf(stderr, "stdin:%d: Unable to read value: \"%s\" makes no sense.\n", line_number, buffer);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        printf("Successfully read value %lf\n", value);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```